# Print an array of List

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I would like to print lists in which each one of them has array's elements.

for example, the output should be as follow:

> list[0]={0,1,2,3}
>   list[2]={4,5,6,7}
>   list[3]={12,17,20,25}
>   and so on ....

This is what I got so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list[i].size(); j++) {
        SegY[i].get(j); SegX[i].get(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that you have Array of List ?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {

     for (int j = 0; j < list[i].size(); j++) {
    list[i].get(j);
    
   }

Comment: I have both array and arraylist

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "how do I print the content of an array", you can use the [`Arrays.deepToString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29). So in your case, you could loop over the list and print each array using that method. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    list.add(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
    list.add(new Integer[]{4, 5, 6});
    for (Integer[] array: list) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```